# How do I make IntelliJ IDEA 8.1.x ignore an item in .gitignore

Tags: ide, grails, intellij-idea

I enjoy Git support in Intellij IDEA 8.1.3.  I've been doing some Grails Development on Linux with it.

IDEA seems to be ignoring other files from `.gitignore` like `/tests/reports`, etc. but is not ignoring stacktrace.log.  In other words changes to stacktrace.log show up in the 'changes' window

The contents of my .gitignore file is:

```
*.iws
.DS_Store
/out/**

# web application files that are overwritten by "grails upgrade"
#  cf. GRAILS_HOME/scripts/Upgrade.groovy, target( upgrade )
/web-app/WEB-INF

# IDE support files that are overwritten by "grails upgrade"
#  cf. GRAILS_HOME/scripts/CreateApp.groovy, target( createIDESupportFiles )
# to be specific, you could replace "/*" below with your project name,
#  e.g. "foobar.launch" (no slash)
.classpath
.project
.settings
/*.launch
/*.tmproj

# logs
stacktrace.log
/test/reports

# project release file
*.war

/classes
```

Am I missing something obvious?
How do I make IDEA 8.1.3 ignore all items from .gitignore?

Comment: Are you using the Git plug-in?

Comment: Yes I am using the Git plugin that came built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `.gitignore` while `stacktrace.log` was still in the repository.
When I updated the `.gitignore`, I expected IDEA to ignore `stacktrace.log`.

On the command-line when I ran `git status` I wouldn't see anything for `stacktrace.log`, but it was showing up as changed in the IDEA Changes window/tab.  After I deleted the `stacktrace.log` and refreshed in IDEA, it no longer showed in the changes window/tab.

Not that big of a deal really.